Transition in lemma proof in maximum set proof
(Sorry if it doesn't render MathJax right, I haven't figured out how it works here)
I've been reading a lot of proofs of existence of maximal set and here is the problem. I'm working with proofs that use marker labelling and priority method. In all of them we proof the second lemma that $\overline A$ $\cap$ $\overline W_{e}$ is finite or  $\overline A$ $\cap$ $W_{e}$ is finite
where A is the c.e. set we want to be maximal, $W_{e}$ is c.e. too
But I have to proof that |$W_{e}$ - A| < $\infty$ or |$\omega$ - $W_{e}$| < $\infty$
I have no ideas how to make such transition, would appreciate your ideas and answers

"$\overline{A}\cap W_e$ is finite" means that there are only finitely many things in $W_e$ that aren't in $A$; this is exactly saying $\vert W_e-A\vert<\infty$.
Now it is not true that "$\overline{A}\cap \overline{W_e}$ is finite" means "$W_e$ is cofinite." However, this becomes true if we restrict attention to $W_e$s which contain $A$, since then $\overline{A}\cap\overline{W_e}=\overline{W_e}$. And since these are the only $W_e$s we're interested in, we're happy.
